# Send data from Android Thread class to Service Class

Tags: android, multithreading, service

You may thing this question is a duplicate one but still I did not find answer in other posts

I have a service class named "Update" and seperate thread class named as "SyncData" within the service. I need to run SyncData thread in onCreate() method of service class. When thread starts running it will run for only once and it should get back the string value to Service onCreate() method. But in my case it always ruturns null in Service onCreate() method. But I see that same data string in my Thread class by putting logs.

In many different posts I see passing data from thread to activity or passing data between Threads by handlers. I dont see any Posts on sending data from thread to service class.

Can someone help me on this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Because if you spawn a new thread the onCreate method returns not waiting the thread to finish. On the other hand you can't block it otherwise you would block the ui thread and result in ANR error

Comment: I understand, but how can I acheive this kind of task?

Comment: you can't. The only thing you can have is a callback called somewhere when the thread is done. But you can't block onCreate()

Comment: what about onStartCommand() or any other place in service class?

Comment: That's fine, but you can get the same result with an asynctask (and maybe it's more userfriendly)

Comment: Can you please provide me any tutorial or working thing on having asynctask within service and send data to service class?

Comment: Just have an inner class that implemetns asynctask. In onPostExecute call your service's method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26158/discussion-between-user1810931-and-fedepaol)

Answer (score 0):

```
Make the String value static and define it in service class.
Eg: 

public class abcd extends service
{
public static String string;
....
.......
... oncreate()
{
Thread t=new Thread(new Otherclass());
t.start();
}
}

Try this . Also be sure to stopservice only after executing thread.
```

Comment: @user1810931 how did u return value from a thread.... public void run (){  } cant return strings

Comment: I get the String value as null